# Access log after $request_uri changes

Tags: nginx, log-files

i have something like this in my nginx.conf file.

```
location / {

    if ($request_uri ~ "^(.*)/(.*)/(.*).*$" ) {
        set  $first  $1;
        set  $second $2;
        set  $third $3;
    }

    proxy_pass http://amigo/newbasedir/$third;
}
```

This changes http://myhost.com/first/second/trhee.html to http://mybackend/newbasedir/trhee.html

but in my access.log config i get registered the original $request_uri and not the newbasedir. Exists any way to change the access.log to save the result request instead of the original?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html. However, in general, it is the responsibility of the software in `amigo` to produce its own logs with the paths it gets.

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite the request, it will show the new URI in the access logs:

```
rewrite "^/[^/]+/[^/]+(/[^/]+)" /newbasedir$1;

location /newbasedir/ {
    proxy_pass http://amigo;
}
```